# What features lack on metacpan.org that are on search.cpan.org?

Tags: perl, cpan

There are 2 popular sites to access Perl open source libraries:

- http://search.cpan.org/
- https://metacpan.org/

search.cpan.org is very old and it worked great for a long period of time. From the other side there is metacpan.org is is only 2 years old but it has s lot of great features.

I myself use metacpan.org and don't use search.cpan.org at all but I'm not a super advanced user. I want to find out is search.cpan.org needed in the modern life? Are there any features lack on metacpan.org that makes it impossible to stop using search.cpan.org?

Why anybody prefer to use search.cpan.org nowadays?

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question but is related: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=922701

Comment: metacpan doesn't list TRIAL modules, while search.cpan.org does. For example, try looking for the experimental “twigils” module.